# How do size a simulated smartphone screen in a responsive div?

Tags: html, css, iframe, responsive-design

So I'm trying to show off a mobile site within a div that looks like a smartphone that is placed on a responsive html5 site. I've messed with the CSS so that the smartphone div keeps a solid aspect ratio as the width of the window is adjusted. Now I am trying to fit an iframe within the div to simulate the phone's screen. **The problem I run into is that my responsive CSS trick is messing with the position of the screen.**

Here is a jFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/E6X4j/2/

I've tried to position it relative, but that messes with the responsive trick in CSS. Any suggestions?

HTML:

```
<div id="smartphonewidth">
<div id="smartphoneheight">
    <object type="text/html" data="http://www.engadget.com" style="width:100%; height:100%;">    
    </object>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#smartphonewidth {
      margin-left: 5%;
      background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/lavEp8B.png?1?5267');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 50%;
      padding: 20%;
      background-size: 100% 100%;}

#smartphoneheight {
    position: absolute;}
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem somehow?

Comment: http://brazos-portal.bp-3cloud.com/?signup=true#

Answer (score 0):

Use this link [**CSS3 media queries for reponsive design**](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/)

To target small devices we can use the following syntax:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
          //your css here
    }
```

please check this [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/E6X4j/3/)

**CSS:**

```
#smartphonewidth {
          margin-left: 5%;
          background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/lavEp8B.png?1?5267');
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          width: 50%;
          padding: 20%;
          background-size: 100% 100%;

}

#smartphoneheight {
    position: relative;
    z-index:1;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not concerned with the screen resolution. The responsive part of the website already runs. My problem is related to a div within another div.

Comment: check my fiddle in the answer and reply the problems..!!

Comment: I think I'm wording my situation poorly. This image of an iPhone is being placed on a responsive html5 site. My goal is for the iPhone image to have a iFrame of another website inside the image's screen area. Does that help? I know I have a inception-style problem going on.

Comment: hey check out my fiddle i have provided..!! it does exactly what you require right..??

Comment: I've tried that, but the problem with switching #smartphoneheight from position absolute is that the aspect ratio of the iPhone image is no longer constant as the user changes the page width. If you go back to my jFiddle, you can change the width of the html page and the phone already stays the same aspect ratio. I do appreciate the effort though!

Answer (score 0):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kurbhatt/E6X4j/4/)

```
#smartphonewidth {
          margin-left: 5%;
          background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/lavEp8B.png?1?5267');
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          width: 58%;
          padding: 15%;
          background-size: 100% 100%;
}

#smartphoneheight {
    height: 15%;
position: relative;
margin-bottom: -69px;
margin-top: -50px;
}


<div id="smartphonewidth">
    <div id="smartphoneheight">
        <object type="text/html" data="http://www.engadget.com" style="width:100%; height:70%;">    
        </object>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem with switching #smartphoneheight position from absolute is that now the smartphone image is not responsive to when the user changes the page width. In my original jFiddle, the smartphone image maintained aspect ratio no matter the page width.